# Gráfico estilo pirámide en ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el dataframe que aparece en la imagen anterior y me gustaría sacar un gráfico parecido al siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Al menos deberías de compartir un avance de los que has intentado hacer.

Comment: Te dejo una ayuda. https://www.njtierney.com/post/2022/08/09/ggplot-pyramid/

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.